# Reshaping the data into a panel by summing up if a certain obseravtion appears more than once?

Tags: r, dataframe, panel, reshape, data-wrangling

I have data (df_input) about schools with the year of establishment (year_est) for four different villages(A,B,C,D).

```
df_input <- data.frame( school_id= c(1,2,3,4,5,6), village= c("A","B","B","C","D","D"), year_est = c(2002,2002,2004,2001,2004,2004))    

df_output <- data.frame(year= c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004), 
                        village = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"), 
                        school_est=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2))
```

I am trying to reshape the format of df_ouput, where the variable "school_est" takes value 1 if a school is established in the village otherwise remains 0.

Additionally, if there is more than one school established in a particular village then the variable school_est can take a value greater than 1, for instance, for village B in the year 2004 in df_output.

It is also common in my dataset that, more than one school is established in the same village in the same year, as is the case with village D in 2004. So in the df_output dataset, the school_est takes the value = 2 in the year 2004 from 0 in 2003.

Can someone help me solve this?

I am using the following code to produce df_output:

```
df_panel <- df_input %>%
  merge(expand.grid(year=2001:2004, Village=.$Village), by="Village") %>% 
  mutate(across(year_est, ~ as.numeric(replace_na(.x <= year, 0))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took longer than expected

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_input <- data.frame( school_id= c(1,2,3,4,5,6), village= c("A","B","B","C","D","D"), year_est = c(2002,2002,2004,2001,2004,2004))    


df_input %>%
  group_by(village, year_est) %>%
  summarise(school_est = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  complete(nesting(village), year_est = seq(min(year_est), max(year_est),1), fill = list(school_est = 0)) %>%
  group_by(village) %>%
  mutate(school_est = cumsum(school_est)) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#>    village year_est school_est
#>    <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 A           2001          0
#>  2 A           2002          1
#>  3 A           2003          1
#>  4 A           2004          1
#>  5 B           2001          0
#>  6 B           2002          1
#>  7 B           2003          1
#>  8 B           2004          2
#>  9 C           2001          1
#> 10 C           2002          1
#> 11 C           2003          1
#> 12 C           2004          1
#> 13 D           2001          0
#> 14 D           2002          0
#> 15 D           2003          0
#> 16 D           2004          2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_input %>% 
   count(village, year = year_est, name = 'school_est') %>% 
   complete(village, year  = min(year):max(year), 
       fill = list(school_est = 0)) %>% 
   mutate(school_est = ave(school_est, village, FUN = cumsum))
```

-ouptut

```
 # A tibble: 16 x 3
   village  year school_est
   <chr>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A        2001          0
 2 A        2002          1
 3 A        2003          1
 4 A        2004          1
 5 B        2001          0
 6 B        2002          1
 7 B        2003          1
 8 B        2004          2
 9 C        2001          1
10 C        2002          1
11 C        2003          1
12 C        2004          1
13 D        2001          0
14 D        2002          0
15 D        2003          0
16 D        2004          2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <- transform(as.data.frame(table(transform(df_input, 
   year_est = factor(year_est, levels = min(year_est):max(year_est)))[-1])), 
     Freq = ave(Freq, village, FUN = cumsum))
out[order(out$village),]
   village year_est Freq
1        A     2001    0
5        A     2002    1
9        A     2003    1
13       A     2004    1
2        B     2001    0
6        B     2002    1
10       B     2003    1
14       B     2004    2
3        C     2001    1
7        C     2002    1
11       C     2003    1
15       C     2004    1
4        D     2001    0
8        D     2002    0
12       D     2003    0
16       D     2004    2
```

Comment: Hello Akrun! Thanks a lot. But there is one problem with this code, the column school_id keeps on increasing. And also 2004 D is reproduced twice. Please see the dput of the result after runnign the suggested code:      structure(list(year_est = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004
), village = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), school_id = c(0, 0, 4, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -17L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))